# How to set the cell width (HTML table) from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have an HTML table. How can I change the width of one of the cells of that table from Javascript code? For example, I have a button, and when I press it, I want the width of one particular column to be changed. How can I do this?

Comment: Please have a look at this question [here][1]. It answers your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130663/using-javascript-to-change-table-cells-width

Comment: or this: [How do I change the column width in a table using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042075/how-do-i-change-the-column-width-in-a-table-using-javascript)

Comment: thank you! Sorry, I didn't saw that question.

Comment: This answer helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130663/using-javascript-to-change-table-cells-width

Comment: You can try **clientWidth** property as:

    var tdWidth = document.getElementById('td');
    alert(tdWidth.clientWidth);     
**clientWidth** returns only numeric part of width, for example, if the width is 50px then it would return **50**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you might do it with jQuery, a popular JavaScript library:

http://jsfiddle.net/VJTnN/2

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').css('width', '100px');
```

Answer (score 8):

You could do it without jQuery.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qFDBk/1/

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
    var td = tbl.rows[0].cells[0];
    td.width = '500px';
    td.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving an example that doesn't require jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS method to apply the width.

```
$('td').css('width','200px');
```

explanation :

1. Get All td Elements. and Apply the CSS property width and set it's value to 200px. for every td element.
2. `$('td')` is the tagSelector. it will select all td elements.
3. .css() will apply the style rules which u mentioned.